# Открыть новое окно при клике в PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Здравствуйте, есть код по шаблону MVC. Прикрепляю код модели и контроллера ( вид не прикрепляю, так как наврят ли тут он нужен)

```
from PyQt5 import  QtWidgets
from view import  Authorization_view
from model import AuthorizationModel

if __name__ == "__main__":
    def press_reg_button_reflect(local_ui: Authorization_view, local_model):
        local_model.registration_data()
        local_ui.registr_status.setText(local_model.text)

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    authorization = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Authorization_view(authorization)

    # Components Events adding
    model = AuthorizationModel(ui)

    ui.registation_button.clicked.connect(lambda: press_reg_button_reflect(ui, model))

    authorization.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Модель:

```
class AuthorizationModel:
    def __init__(self, ui: Authorization_view):
        self.enter_login = ui.enter_loginlineEdit.text()
        self.enter_password = ui.enter_password_lineEdit.text()
        self.enter_name = ui.enter_name_lineEdit_3.text()
        self.enter_surname = ui.enter_surname_lineEdit_2.text()
        self.enter_email = ui.enter_mail_lineEdit_4.text()

    def registration_data(self):
        self.info = [self.enter_login,self.enter_password,self.enter_name,self.enter_surname,self.enter_email]
        print(self.info)
        if len(self.enter_login) <6:
            self.text = 'Too short login!'
        elif len(self.enter_password) <6:
            self.text = 'Too short password!'
        elif len(self.enter_name) <3:
            self.text = 'Too short name!'
        elif len(self.enter_surname) <3:
            self.text = 'Too short surname!'
        elif re.match(r'[\w\S]{2}@[a-z]+\.[a-z]{2}',self.enter_email) == None:
            self.text = 'Wrong e-mail!'
        else:
            self.text = 'Registration successful'
```

Нужно сделать так, что бы при клике на кнопку (ui.registation_button.clicked.connect) вместо того, что бы у меня изменялся текст на label'е ( local_ui.registr_status.setText(local_model.text) ) открывалось новое диалоговое окно с этим текстом, как такое реализировать?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать стандартный клевый диалог – [QInputDialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputdialog.html):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QInputDialog

app = QApplication([])

text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(None, "My Dialog", "Input text:", text="Current text")
if ok:
    print(text)
```

Вот так будет выглядеть он:

[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

---

А ваша функция будет выглядеть например вот так:

```
def press_reg_button_reflect(local_ui: Authorization_view, local_model):
    text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(None, "My Dialog", "Input text:", text="Current text")
    if ok:
        local_ui.registr_status.setText(text)
```